# How to change all button, icons and other element color of a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, colors, wordpress-theming, themes

I want to change all yellow color elements to red of my WordPress theme!

I have a new WordPress theme "Eikra" and I want to change its all yellow color to red I try to change it from CSS files but even after changing it from everywhere nothing happens it still shows the yellow color I also try to clear my cache and cookies but still same. Please help me to fix this!

```
#Before 

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #fdc800;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#After 

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #ec3237;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I want to make all element color to #ec3237! I am working on acesonipat.com please help me to do it so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check Eikra theme documentaion and change color from theme options

From Admin menu, navigate to **Appearance -> Eikra Options.** Then go to General tab.
Choose your preferred primary and secondary color from the color palette.

See link https://www.radiustheme.com/demo/wordpress/eikra/docs/

See Attachment [image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify all the elements you want to change.

```css
.class-1, . class-2, .class-3{color:#ec3237;}

.class-1:hover, . class-2:hover, .class-3:hover,
.class-1:focus, . class-2:focus, .class-3:focus,
.class-1:active, . class-2:active, .class-3:active{color:#fdc800;}
```

Use your browser inspect tool.

Comment: `. class-x` is not a valid selector. You need to remove the space after the dot.